# After Users import from CSVDE User Logon Name is incorrect

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I have imported a load of Active Directory Users using CSVDE into my Windows 2008 R2 test domain but am having problems logging in with them.
The import went successfully and the users were created exactly as I expected them to be however when i enabled an account and tested login on a client machine it failed with the error bad username or password.
I had a quick look at the AD properties for the users and noticed that all the imported users did not have the correct User logon name (Pre Windows 2000) once I corrected this on my test user they could log on fine. I have been through the import.csv and compared it to an export.csv from the same domain. there doesn't seem to be any occurences of the username missing in my import.

I have attached a sample of the import csv file for examination.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
DN  objectClass distinguishedName   name    objectCategory  cn  displayName sn  givenName   userPrincipalName
CN=Abligail Bleasby,OU=LBS,DC=North,DC=local    user    CN=Abligail Bleasby,OU=LBS,DC=North,DC=local    Abligail Bleasby    CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=North,DC=local  Abligail Bleasby    Abligail Bleasby    Bleasby Abligail    ableasby@North.local
CN=Benjamin Hastie,OU=LBS,DC=North,DC=local user    CN=Benjamin Hastie,OU=LBS,DC=North,DC=local Benjamin Hastie CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=North,DC=local  Benjamin Hastie Benjamin Hastie Hastie  Benjamin    bhastie@North.local
CN=Charlotte Blaylock,OU=LBS,DC=North,DC=local  user    CN=Charlotte Blaylock,OU=LBS,DC=North,DC=local  Charlotte Blaylock  CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=North,DC=local  Charlotte Blaylock  Charlotte Blaylock  Blaylock    Charlotte   cblaylock@North.local
CN=Charlotte Heyes,OU=LBS,DC=North,DC=local user    CN=Charlotte Heyes,OU=LBS,DC=North,DC=local Charlotte Heyes CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=North,DC=local  Charlotte Heyes Charlotte Heyes Heyes   Charlotte   cmeheyes@North.local
CN=Gavin Dell,OU=LBS,DC=North,DC=local  user    CN=Gavin Dell,OU=LBS,DC=North,DC=local  Gavin Dell  CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=North,DC=local  Gavin Dell  Gavin Dell  Dell    Gavin   gdell@North.local
CN=Jamie Barnes,OU=LBS,DC=North,DC=local    user    CN=Jamie Barnes,OU=LBS,DC=North,DC=local    Jamie Barnes    CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=North,DC=local  Jamie Barnes    Jamie Barnes    Barnes  Jamie   jbarnes3@North.local
CN=Jeanne Hill,OU=LBS,DC=North,DC=local user    CN=Jeanne Hill,OU=LBS,DC=North,DC=local Jeanne Hill CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=North,DC=local  Jeanne Hill Jeanne Hill Hill    Jeanne  jhill1@North.local
CN=Jennifer Norris,OU=LBS,DC=North,DC=local user    CN=Jennifer Norris,OU=LBS,DC=North,DC=local Jennifer Norris CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=North,DC=local  Jennifer Norris Jennifer Norris Norris  Jennifer    jnorris2@North.local
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved.
As soon as I read through the question I realised what I'd missed but put it up here as I've seen other unanswered versions knocking about the Net.
The missing column is sAMAccountName, once that is added to the table in the format of the username e.g ableasby for my imaginary people then it populates the Pre Windows 20000 logon name field.
Hope this helps any others who come across it.